# Add user in Azure AD using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add user using Microsoft graph API.

I have provided the consent for all the permissions required.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Request body that is send to the post request.

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Adele Vance",
    "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
    "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
    }
}
```

Error that is received in response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://outlook.office365.com:444/profile/v1.0/users('CID:0ff49e4749deeaf2')/profile?api-version=AGSV1-internal'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-04T10:41:56",
            "request-id": "025218e1-191c-464f-adf3-f0cdc5fcebfd",
            "client-request-id": "c071d220-2f14-d7fa-956e-cd45ccbdc735"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something that I am missing?

I have also gone through the docs for adding user provided by Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: The above looks perfectly fine to me  Have you tested it in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)

Comment: Did you execute multiple requests? Can you provide your code?

Comment: What is the exact request? Do you have single tenat or multitenant app?

Comment: I was able to add add user using an Organisation account but not through personal account. I was adding user using Microsoft Graph API. I have tested it on Graph Explorer as well.

Comment: It does not support Microsoft personal accounts.

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it to end the thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you said in the comment is correct, the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) has detailed instructions, it does **not support** Microsoft personal accounts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the  end point are you using to authorize in order to obtain the token.

If you are using a tenant specific end point

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e

Try replacing with the common endpoint

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth....
```